# Conversion of Fahrenheit to Celsius with MASM assembler

Tags: assembly, masm, low-level

I am learning how to code low-level language and I am trying to write a program that will get the degree Fahrenheit from the user then convert it into degree Celsius with this operation

```
( 5/9 ) * (input- 32)
```

To get the result I first compute

```
5*(input - 32)
```

which leaves the product in `ax` and then divide by 9, but then I am getting the wrong result.
Thanks for the help.

```
include PCMAC.INC
.model small
.586
.stack 100h
.data
  msg        db 'Enter  the degree in fahrenheit:  $'
  input      dw ?
  cel        dw ?
  outputmsg  db " Conversion done, result is $"
  outputmsg2 db " celsius", 13, 10, '$'
  A          dw 5   
  B          dw 9   
.code
  extrn GetDec:near, PutDec:near
  main      PROC
    _Begin 
    _Putstr msg          
    call GetDec     

    mov input, ax   

    mov bl, 32
    sub al, bl
    ; sub ax, 32

    mov cx, A
    imul cx

    mov cx, B
    idiv cx

    mov cel, ax

    _putstr outputmsg
    call PutDec

    _putstr outputmsg2
    _Exit 0
  main endp
end  main
```

I just edited the code, now I am getting the right answers when the Celsius is positive but when my answer(Celsius) is negative the result is wrong I am not sure how to get a negative degree celsius

Comment: The `imul B` and `idiv A` look wrong to me - and I wouldn't have thought that would compile, but my masm is rusty. Why not just 5 and 9 inline? As it stands it might be interpreting that as `imul offset B`. When you say 'getting wrong result', what do your wrong results look like? Can you give us an example?

Comment: I did try to put 5 and 9 inline but still, I got the same result. By wrong answer I mean when I input a number like 68 I am supposed to get 20-degree Celsius but instead, I get 2324 degree which I don't get how.

Comment: Does `_putstr` overwrite ax?  Many routines do, but I'm not familiar with PCMAC.INC.  You could try adding `mov ax, cel` to restore the value before PutDec.  Walking this with a debugger (a useful skill for an assembler programmer) might also make the problem clear.

Comment: No it does not, I found the first problem which is on " sub ax, 32 "

Comment: I changed this way " mov bl, 32 " then " sub al, bl "

Comment: @T.243 You are introducing new problem. This works only because al is not too small. When al is smaller enough there will be borrow and your answer will be wrong.

Comment: yeah, I think that is what's happening when my input is less than 32, I am supposed to get a negative number but instead, I get a wrong number. How do I fix that

Answer (score 2):

```
Mov cx, [B]
Imul cx
Mov cx, [A]
Idiv cx
```

When in doubt of something like this, disassemble your code again. I distinctly remember imul and idiv not liking non-register arguments when using masm

Also, always put ? after non ? dw values. Crazy impossible bugs otherwise.

Comment: that worked also but the problem was on the subtraction part, I talk on " sub ax, 32 ". I changed this way " mov bl, 32 " then " sub al, bl "

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why I could not get any negative result (degree). Before, the size of my register was too small to hold bits for negative numbers so in order to correct that I used EAX registers to make the space way bigger.

include PCMAC.INC

.model small
.586
.stack 100h
.data

msg        db 'Enter  the degree in fahrenheit:  $'

input      dw ?

cel        dw ?

outputmsg  db " Conversion done, result is $"

outputmsg2 db " celsius", 13, 10, '$'

A          dw 5

B          dw 9

.code

extrn GetDec:near, PutDec:near
  main      PROC

```
_Begin 

_Putstr msg          


call GetDec     

mov input, ax   

mov ebx, 32
sub eax, ebx
;mov bl, 32
;sub al, bl
; sub ax, 32

mov cx, A
imul cx
;mov cx, A
;imul cx


mov cx, B
idiv cx
;mov cx, B
;idiv cx


mov dx, 0
mov cx, ax
;mov cel, ax

_putstr outputmsg
mov eax, ecx
call PutDec
```